# Change TextView value in new Activity

Tags: android, textview

I don't know how to change value of TextView when i start a new Activity. So i have an adapter for ListView, when i click on the first position i open a new activity, where i have a TextView that i want to modify.

```
   switch(position){                
   case 0:
          Intent amazonas = new Intent(Bezalkoholowe.this, Amazonas.class);     
          startActivity(amazonas);
          break;
```

This start a new activity. I tried to make this on the onCreate method in new Activity:

```
  TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
  text.setText("bla bla bla");
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how should I do that?

(Edit)
Here is the XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/am1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" 
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    />

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the onCreate method:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_amazonas);       
      text.setText(R.string.amazonas);
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }       
  }
```

Wrapping it in the switch condition didn't give any results.

Comment: We need to see your code, specifically your xml and the onCreate methods where you are trying to set your text.

Comment: Make sure `R.id.textView` is referring to the `TextView` of `Amazonas` activity layout. Check your xml layout file.